# .hide and .show displaying all elements and not functioning properly until user scrolls

Tags: javascript, hide, show, show-hide, scrolltop

Hello so I am working on a vertical scrolling site where fixed central image (the main character) hide and show depending on where the user is on the page using .scrolltop. The only problem I have is that when the page loads the first time, every single central image loads at once and is displayed. Once you begin scrolling it works correctly from the point on, it seems to only happen when the page is first loaded. What am I writing wrong in my script? I think it has to do with the .hide function not activating until the user scrolls, but I dont know how to write it differently.

Thank you.

Here's the site so you can see what I'm talking about:

http://pixel.csueastbay.edu/3870/corzine/project1/index.html

And here's a sample of the js:

```
<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 290) {
    $(".fallingman").hide();
}

if ($(this).scrollTop() < 290) {
    $(".fallingman").show();
}

});




$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(this).scrollTop() < 290) {
    $(".fallingman2").hide();
}

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 290) {
    $(".fallingman2").show();
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1200) {
    $(".fallingman2").hide();
}

});

</script>
```

Comment: You're doing your checks inside `$(window).scroll()` handler, so of course it only runs when you scroll. If you want something done immediately when the page loads, put it at the top-level of the `$(document).ready()` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put what you want into a function. Then call it unconditionally when the page loads, and also in the scroll handler.

```
function checkScroll() {
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos > 290) {
        $(".fallingman").hide();
        $(".fallingman2").show();
    }
    if (pos < 290) {
        $(".fallingman").show();
        $(".fallingman2").hide();
    }
    if (pos > 1200) {
        $(".fallingman2").show();
    }
)

$(function() {
    checkScroll();
    $(window).scroll(checkScroll);
});
```